# Create closed or secret events with Graph API

Tags: ios, facebook, events, facebook-graph-api

Setting `privacy` to `SECRET` in the POST request as suggested by the documentation does not work. I tried both through my own code and Graph API Explorer. The created event is always public.

Is this simply not supported or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution to this problem at http://codecri.me/article/373/create-an-event-using-the-facebook-graph-api-in-php/

Apparently the correct key to set for event privacy is `privacy_type` and not `privacy` as suggested by the documentation.

Hope this helps somebody...

Comment: Where in the documentation did you see `privacy` listed as a parameter for event creation? I can get it updated so nobody else has the same issue. According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#events the parameter is indeed `privacy_type`

Comment: Thanks for the link to the User documentation I had not seen it. I was looking at the Events documentation under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/